# pyqtgraph: problem setting smooth=False on a GLSurfacePlotItem object

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqtgraph, qtgui

I'm currently trying to plot a basic color-coded 'slice' in 3D using `pyqtgraph`. When I initialize the `GLSurfacePlotItem` object with `smooth=True` everything works fine. However I get a massive amount of errors and warnings when I simply set `smooth=False`. Unfortunately the documentation does not really explain much about this setting.

Below is my example code. What am I missing?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import sys
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from pyqtgraph.Qt import QtCore, QtGui
import pyqtgraph.opengl as gl
import pyqtgraph as pg

x, y, z = 30, 20, 10
data = np.random.rand(x,y,z)

cmap = matplotlib.cm.get_cmap('jet')
norm = matplotlib.colors.PowerNorm(vmin=0.0, vmax=1.0, gamma=2.5)
m = matplotlib.cm.ScalarMappable(norm=norm, cmap=cmap)

colors = np.zeros((x,y,z,4), dtype=np.float16)
for i in range(x):
    colors[i,:,:,:] = m.to_rgba(data[i,:,:])

app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
w = gl.GLViewWidget()

zslice = gl.GLSurfacePlotItem(x=np.arange(0,x,1), y=np.arange(0,y,1), z=np.ones((x,y))*0.5, colors=colors[:,:,0,:], smooth=True, computeNormals=False)

w.addItem(zslice)
w.setGeometry(100, 10, 1280, 720)
w.show()

if (sys.flags.interactive != 1) or not hasattr(QtCore, 'PYQT_VERSION'):
    QtGui.QApplication.instance().exec_()
```

The error message I get when I set `smooth=False`:

```
[13:16:04]

    |==============================>>
    |  Traceback (most recent call last):
    |    File "./test5.py", line 34, in <module>
    |      QtGui.QApplication.instance().exec_()
    |    File "/home/steve/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyqtgraph/opengl/GLViewWidget.py", line 179, in paintGL
    |      self.drawItemTree(useItemNames=useItemNames)
    |    File "/home/steve/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyqtgraph/opengl/GLViewWidget.py", line 219, in drawItemTree
    |      self.drawItemTree(i, useItemNames=useItemNames)
    |    File "/home/steve/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyqtgraph/opengl/GLViewWidget.py", line 200, in drawItemTree
    |      debug.printExc()
    |    --- exception caught here ---
    |    File "/home/steve/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyqtgraph/opengl/GLViewWidget.py", line 197, in drawItemTree
    |      i.paint()
    |    File "/home/steve/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyqtgraph/opengl/items/GLMeshItem.py", line 167, in paint
    |      self.parseMeshData()
    |    File "/home/steve/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyqtgraph/opengl/items/GLMeshItem.py", line 151, in parseMeshData
    |      self.colors = md.vertexColors(indexed='faces')
    |    File "/home/steve/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyqtgraph/opengl/MeshData.py", line 239, in vertexColors
    |      self._vertexColorsIndexedByFaces = self._vertexColors[self.faces()]
    |  IndexError: index 30 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 30
    |==============================<<
Error while drawing item <pyqtgraph.opengl.items.GLSurfacePlotItem.GLSurfacePlotItem object at 0x7f9f0cf21410>.
[13:16:04]

    |==============================>>
    |  Traceback (most recent call last):
    |    File "./test5.py", line 34, in <module>
    |      QtGui.QApplication.instance().exec_()
    |    File "/home/steve/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyqtgraph/opengl/GLViewWidget.py", line 179, in paintGL
    |      self.drawItemTree(useItemNames=useItemNames)
    |    File "/home/steve/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyqtgraph/opengl/GLViewWidget.py", line 219, in drawItemTree
    |      self.drawItemTree(i, useItemNames=useItemNames)
    |    File "/home/steve/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyqtgraph/opengl/GLViewWidget.py", line 200, in drawItemTree
    |      debug.printExc()
    |    --- exception caught here ---
    |    File "/home/steve/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyqtgraph/opengl/GLViewWidget.py", line 197, in drawItemTree
    |      i.paint()
    |    File "/home/steve/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyqtgraph/opengl/items/GLMeshItem.py", line 167, in paint
    |      self.parseMeshData()
    |    File "/home/steve/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyqtgraph/opengl/items/GLMeshItem.py", line 151, in parseMeshData
    |      self.colors = md.vertexColors(indexed='faces')
    |    File "/home/steve/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyqtgraph/opengl/MeshData.py", line 239, in vertexColors
    |      self._vertexColorsIndexedByFaces = self._vertexColors[self.faces()]
    |  IndexError: index 30 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 30
    |==============================<<
Error while drawing item <pyqtgraph.opengl.items.GLSurfacePlotItem.GLSurfacePlotItem object at 0x7f9f0cf21410>.
[13:16:04]

    |==============================>>
    |  Traceback (most recent call last):
    |    File "./test5.py", line 34, in <module>
    |      QtGui.QApplication.instance().exec_()
    |    File "/home/steve/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyqtgraph/opengl/GLViewWidget.py", line 179, in paintGL
    |      self.drawItemTree(useItemNames=useItemNames)
    |    File "/home/steve/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyqtgraph/opengl/GLViewWidget.py", line 219, in drawItemTree
    |      self.drawItemTree(i, useItemNames=useItemNames)
    |    File "/home/steve/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyqtgraph/opengl/GLViewWidget.py", line 200, in drawItemTree
    |      debug.printExc()
    |    --- exception caught here ---
    |    File "/home/steve/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyqtgraph/opengl/GLViewWidget.py", line 197, in drawItemTree
    |      i.paint()
    |    File "/home/steve/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyqtgraph/opengl/items/GLMeshItem.py", line 167, in paint
    |      self.parseMeshData()
    |    File "/home/steve/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyqtgraph/opengl/items/GLMeshItem.py", line 151, in parseMeshData
    |      self.colors = md.vertexColors(indexed='faces')
    |    File "/home/steve/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyqtgraph/opengl/MeshData.py", line 239, in vertexColors
    |      self._vertexColorsIndexedByFaces = self._vertexColors[self.faces()]
    |  IndexError: index 30 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 30
    |==============================<<
Error while drawing item <pyqtgraph.opengl.items.GLSurfacePlotItem.GLSurfacePlotItem object at 0x7f9f0cf21410>.
[13:16:06]

    |==============================>>
    |  Traceback (most recent call last):
    |    File "./test5.py", line 34, in <module>
    |      QtGui.QApplication.instance().exec_()
    |    File "/home/steve/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyqtgraph/opengl/GLViewWidget.py", line 179, in paintGL
    |      self.drawItemTree(useItemNames=useItemNames)
    |    File "/home/steve/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyqtgraph/opengl/GLViewWidget.py", line 219, in drawItemTree
    |      self.drawItemTree(i, useItemNames=useItemNames)
    |    File "/home/steve/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyqtgraph/opengl/GLViewWidget.py", line 200, in drawItemTree
    |      debug.printExc()
    |    --- exception caught here ---
    |    File "/home/steve/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyqtgraph/opengl/GLViewWidget.py", line 197, in drawItemTree
    |      i.paint()
    |    File "/home/steve/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyqtgraph/opengl/items/GLMeshItem.py", line 167, in paint
    |      self.parseMeshData()
    |    File "/home/steve/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyqtgraph/opengl/items/GLMeshItem.py", line 151, in parseMeshData
    |      self.colors = md.vertexColors(indexed='faces')
    |    File "/home/steve/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyqtgraph/opengl/MeshData.py", line 239, in vertexColors
    |      self._vertexColorsIndexedByFaces = self._vertexColors[self.faces()]
    |  IndexError: index 30 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 30
    |==============================<<
Error while drawing item <pyqtgraph.opengl.items.GLSurfacePlotItem.GLSurfacePlotItem object at 0x7f9f0cf21410>.
```

Comment: @eyllanesc I've added it above

Answer (score 1):

The error says "IndexError: index 30 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 30," which suggests that you or the library you are using might be looping 1 through 30 instead of 0 through 29. (Setting smooth=False might send your code to the portion of the library withe the error in it.) Since your x variable is 30, I'm guessing that's the point of origin. The error message says the issue is in ./test5.py", line 34, so I would start there.

Comment: Yup, I see the same, thanks for this answer